# How to click <a> tag in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Below is my code.Am pasting my entire  tag

```
<TR id="oldcontent" bgcolor="#D0D0D0">
<TD  id="oldcontent">Foot-OM</TD>
 <a id="oldcontent" href="ID=22143"><u>Re-Submit</u></a>
 <a id="oldcontent" href="ID=22143"><u>View</u></a>
<TR>
```

Here i need to click the  tag with Re-Submit text.The issue is  href="ID=22143",id value gets generated dynamically everytime i execute the test case.So i need to click the Re-submit  tag using text present in first  text,i.e Foot-OM.Can anyone provide me the xpath>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can click on it like this :

```
selenium.click("//a/u[contains(text(),'Re-Submit')]");
```

For Webdriver :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/u[contains(text(),'Re-Submit')]")).click();
```

Comment: where can I find the selenium object of selenium.click in c#? I'm only familiar with driver.FindElement(...

Answer (score 2):

In ruby Selenium webdriver

```
@driver.find_element(:link, "Re-Submit" ).click
```

using selenium RC perl

```
$sel->click("link=Re-Submit");
```

Comment: Am not using selenium webdriver.just using selenium

Comment: I thought you had selenium2 as one of your tags?

Comment: anyways edited my answer to include selenium RC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is in incorrect HTML structure. Tag `<a>` can't be put into `<tr>`. Only `<td>` is allowed there. Browser "fixes" errors and your tags `<a>` appear outside the table and DOM-structure is not the same as html.

[image: Fixed DOM by Browser]

This XPath works for the picture above

```
//td[text()='Foot-OM']/../../../../a[//text()='Re-Submit']
```

Answer (score 0):

U can simply write 1.selenium.click("link=Re-Submit")  and 
                   2.selenium.click("link-View").